# Filling data structure from file in C with specific parameters

Tags: c, file-io, struct

I am writing a small program that will read a file and will fill a data structure that holds a username and an unknown number of another data structure. For instance here is the struct

```
struct user{
    char username[20];
    struct account bkActs[100];
};
```

I am reading from a file that is in the form of 
username
account type
account number
account balance
(whitespace)
username
.
.

however it is unknown how many accounts the person could have. In the spec it is allowed to have any number of accounts. how can i read the file to fill this?
I have used fscanf before but that only worked because i knew the order in which the data was
written and how many of each. any ideas?

an example would be filling the data structure above with the file
234A23
checking
123123123
1.10
23sdf23
checking
1244332223
1.10
savings
123124444
1000.00

Comment: You might want to read up on deserialization in C. Note that dynamic memory management might be helpful to achieve your goal, especially also if the usernames might be longer than 19 chars at some point.

Comment: i know that the username has to be less than 20 (part of the spec). All of that is fine. The part I don't understand is how to parse the file correctly

Comment: You might want to add an example to your question (the actual text for a few users, where some have multiple accounts). It's hard to give advice on writing a parser when I don't know what I'm parsing.

Comment: You can write a book on that topic. Unless you have a specific question on the implementation (which you just didn't state yet, maybe you should clarify?), this question should probably rather be closed (because it's too broad).

Comment: You need a looping structure that can read an arbitrary number of 'one line containing user name, followed by N groups of three lines containing account information, followed by either a blank line or EOF'.  If you get EOF after reading account type but before reading balance successfully, you've got malformed input.

Comment: so eof is equivalent to whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function fgets. it will return NULL on end of file:

```
while (fgets(buf, n, fp)!=NULL) {

  //do stuff with buf

}
```

read up on [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm). there is also the function [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), though it might at first be a bit trickier to use (for example you have to check errno to see if you reached end of file or if an error occured).

Comment: Since this code won't recognize newlines as in anyway special, it is likely to be harder to deal with this input than with line-based input via `fgets()` or `getline()` (from POSIX 2008).

Comment: thanks, thats actually a better idea. i focused too much on just explaining the EOF concept

Comment: I don't see `getline()` as significantly harder to use than `fgets()`.  The loop condition is `while ((nbytes = getline(&buffer, &bufsiz, fp)) > 0)` which is only marginally more complex than `fgets()` (because it contains an assignment) and similar to `while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)`.  In some contexts, it is easier to use than `fgets()` because it tells you how many characters were read.